# Obtener mensajes de stored procedure en php

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin, stored-procedure

Hola podria alguien ayudarme con lo siguiente cuando ejecuto SP me da el sigueinte resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y con este codigo puedo obtener el resultado que quiero y enviarlo no hay problema
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema esta cuando mi SP devuelve un mensaje y no se como mostralo en el codigo PHP que es similar al de imagen anterior espero alguien me pueda ayudar muchas gracias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: pues abajo puedes poner if($ffinal1){ enviar_texto("la fecha final es $ffinal1");} else { $mensaje= $rfinal['Mensaje']; enviar_texto($mensaje) }

Comment: Puedes usar 
if ($rfinal[0]=="Se registro corrrectamente")
y comparar si fue un registro o una consulta

Comment: @KeTeMeTo funciono .muchas gracias

Comment: Sugerencia: el código se comparte como texto. Para personas en móviles o con dificultades visuales, leer tu pregunta será mucho más difícil.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes acceder a la propiedad de esta manera:

```
if($ffinal1){ 
   enviar_texto("la fecha final es $ffinal1");
} 
else { 
   $mensaje= $rfinal['Mensaje']; enviar_texto($mensaje) 
}
```